# S/MIME Mail - signed or not signed - what's the standard procedure for sending to a known recipient

Tags: email, certificate, smime

If you have already exchanged certificates with somebody and you already encrypt emails, do you sign the following emails anyway/again? What is the accepted standard procedure for this? Where is this described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of a (cryptographic) signature on an email is to prove that the sender is who the sender claims to be, and not some one who found an open relay mail server to forge a `From:`.  Therefore one would sign any message that one wants to have proof of origin on, which one presumes would be all messages.

Encrypting means that only the intended recipient(s) can read it, but doesn't say anything about who sent it. So, great, an encrypted mail had an attachment... still throwing it in the trash. Or, I might have a policy to not decrypt it at all because it's bigger than 100kb and unsigned (I don't know of any client that has policies like that, but they're not unreasonable).

Comment: nice policy for safety reasons, I have to think about this.

Comment: In my opinion, it is sufficient if an email address has been verified once. After that, you could do without the overhead of the certificate that you sent each time. So, my point is, that I want to dose exactly who gets my certificate. I do not want it to have my certificate fly around somewhere like my real signature I give not to everyone.

Comment: The part of your certificate that "flies around" is the public part which in fact is intended to be public and available to anyone. Also, this is not the actual intent of a signing a mail. In fact, there are even [reasons not to use the same certificate for signing and encrypting](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1806/why-should-one-not-use-the-same-asymmetric-key-for-encryption-as-they-do-for-sig).